# Custom panel in photoshop with interactive content

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

I would like to have a panel in photoshop with my dynamic content, this content will be a set of textfields used for calculations. I would like to know how can I achieve this.

I've tried with the Adobe Configurator (2.0 and 4.0) but both dont have the input text fields nor ability to add code that will perform calculations later.

I've tried to use SWF but in Configurator 2 after exporting panel was empty, and Configurator 4 doesnt export compatibile extension with CS5.1.

I'm trying with ExtendScript Toolkit but I can open panel type window - which then dont allow to click anywhere else or palette - but this just dissappears immediately:) - EDIT: [Palette vs Dialog](http://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/scriptui-window-in-photoshop-palette-vs-dialog/) explains to me why it dissapears:)

Can anyone point me to the solution?:)

Edit2: [I've also found that SWF's](http://v2.scriptplayground.com/tutorials/as/Creating-Flash-Panels-for-Photoshop-using-Flash-CS4/) should be played in the panels as long as placed in the Panels folder:
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5.1\Plug-ins\Panels\ but it doesnt work for me, hmm.

[The Photoshop SDK page.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html)

Comment: You want a window to be displayed in Photoshop even when no script is running? Or do you only need the window while a script is running?

Comment: anytime, like navigator or info panel

Comment: It's expensive, but the most complete resource out there for this is https://gumroad.com/l/DTkXd/.  You're in for a lot of digging if you choose not to invest in the book, you'll want to start researching HTML5 panels and Generator plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Photoshop CC try [Extension Builder 3](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/extensionbuilder3/) you can build dockable panels with html5
If you are in a version before that use the palette from Script UI, you should take a look into the [Script UI guide by Peter Kahrel](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html)

I think the disappearing palette problem can be solved by setting the `#target photoshop` flag at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Thanks, no, it didn't helped, the palette will disappear unless there is some code running (as described in the link in edited post). I need it working for CS5.1 and possibly CS6 (CC is not important for me as I dont have access to it).